# My Bash script file isn't working properly. Why?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

I am trying to make an automation script using bash. However, the syntax I am using is apparently wrong and I've looked everywhere for a good bash guide but can't find any.

Anyway, take a look at the code below. I commented out how I intend for the script to work.

**script.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

echo "Note: this script will only work if you already ran, [setup.bat] first."
read -p "Did you run [setup.bat] already? <y/n>"

#if $read == y then sh setupKit.sh (run a new shell file)
#if $read == n then setupKit() (Go into a new function)
#Not working the way I want it too.

if [$read == "y"]; then echo "call next script"
if [$read == "n"]; then setupKit()

function setupKit() {
    echo "success"
    #do something
}
```

Comment: Start with the resources listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: `read -p "Did you run [setup.bat] already? <y/n>" response`

Comment: `if [ "$response" == "y" ]; then echo "call next script" ; fi`

Comment: `if [ "$response" == "n" ]; then setupKit ; fi`

Comment: @nobar Thanks dude! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Note: Spaces around punctuation make a difference.  Also, you need to declare `setupKit()` prior to calling it.

Comment: @nobar gotcha, I'll keep that in mind.